# Spring WebSocket multiroom chat

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I want to create chat with multirooms,nad use to Spring. Rooms should be secret and person without permissions should not access to room. How secure tnie rooms ? Aby ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very vague question, but if you want to use Spring, the module [Spring Security](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) is what you're looking for.

You can also check the documentation for [WebSocket security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/websocket.html) (still with Spring Security).